# Spark submit a parallel job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

( have a problem with Apache Spark
I have a cluster with 10 nodes (1 master and 9 slaves), each node has 1048MB of memory.

I work in machine learning, so I'd like to run my implementation in parallel, but I cannot make it work - there is always a single Worker that executes the application I submit.

I tried a simple example of the WordCount, in which I partition the file, but I always get the same result.

Here are my files

`spark-env.s`h (in each node):

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop"
SPARK_YARN_QUEUE="default" 
export SPARK_MASTER_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=9"
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=9"
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
```

The example I've tried:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("path.txt" , 2 ).flatMap(x=>x.split(" ")).map(x=>(x,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
rdd.saveAsTextFile(path)
//I tried 2 distribution hope see two worker execute
```

Here is the configuration with which I submit the application :

```
./spark-submit --master spark://master:6066 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://master:9000/jars/*.jar --conf spark.default.parallelism=2 --class Accueil  hdfs://master:9000/user/word2P.jar hdfs://master:9000/user/twitter.txt  hdfs://master:9000/user/result
```

And here is my Spark UI at the time of execution :

[image]

Comment: You set YARN properties but submit to Spark standalone, that's suspicious. Could you include spark.defaults and the code you use to initialize contexts?

Comment: Other than not using YARN, how large is the input file?

Comment: I work with a dataset <100,000 records (in size, that's 20 to 30MB)